# Insert multiple rows from select into another table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

let's say i have `table1(col1,col2,col3), the values to insert on col1 and col3 will be the same, but the values to insert on col2 come from the result of a select query.

How can i write my query so i can do this multiple insert at once ?
Example of what the query should do :

```
col1  |  col2   | col3

 1        val1     0
 1        val2     0
 1        val3     0
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would use `insert . . .select`:

```
insert into table1(col1, col2, col3)
    select 1, col2, 0
    from <your other query here>;
```

Comment: Can we add Where clauses in the select query here, because sometimes we may want to use only certain rows of second table ?

Comment: @DhumilAgarwal . . . Yes, you can add a `where` clause to the `select`.